# Regarding Card Scanner in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using a card_scanner package in my flutter application but it's showing error, Is implementing card_scanner compatible in my flutter project? Any advice?

Comment: Please share more details, your code, etc.

Comment: at least share error